How to send payload to controller api from interceptor after decrypting it
I am using Java Spring Boot to implement encryption and decryption of payload. I want to create a centralized place where I will decrypt all the incoming request payloads and then send them to the controller APIs decrypted.
for example, earlier API was - api?queryparams=1&queryparam=2
now it is - api?request=encoded-string, now I can get the encoded-string decrypt it and get queryparams=1&queryparam=2
What I am expecting is that it should send the payload to the controller api so the api gives the expected result. However, it is unable to set these values to the controller api.
